# View is not taking any value on android

Tags: android, view

I get this error on my debugger when i try to edit the value manually: Generated value (int) is not compatible with the declared type (android.view.View)

```
    final View l = findViewById(R.id.GameplayLayout);
    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
    android.R.anim.fade_out);
    a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            fadein();
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

    });
    l.startAnimation(a);
```

It selects:

```
    l.startAnimation(a);
```

as error line, in the debugger it says:

```
    l = null;
```

Why is it doing this to me? :(

Thank you!

I had to use R.id.startscreen... Fail... Sorry!

Comment: Why do you want to change the view from the debugger?

Comment: Are you changing the value _while_ debugging or is it crashing because `l` is null? Please post any logcat errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try calling `setContentView(R.layout.GameplayLayout)` before finding views.